# How does NodeJS 'createServer' know to use custom 'port' set in Express app object?

Tags: node.js, express

We can create a nodejs server serving an express application like so:

```
var app = require('express');
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app); // <-- http module from nodejs
server.listen(port);
```

This is actually essentially what express generator gives us

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

However, `'port'` is not defined in the default settings table (in line 3 in snippet above)

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.settings.table

My question is

1. Why do we need to set the port in line 3? `app.set('port', port);`
2. Where is this setting used? (Is it in the `server` object? If so, how does it know to use this setting?)

Comment: I don't know of any use of `app.set('port')` nor is it in the generated Express app. If it *was* used by the server object it'd be in the server source code (but if it is, since there's an explicit `listen`, it'd likely be ignored since that takes its own `port`).

Answer (score 1):

> How does NodeJS 'createServer' know to use custom 'port' set in Express app object?

`http.createServer()` does not have a port or need a port.  The port is applied when the `.listen()` method is called on the server object in this line of your code:

```
server.listen(port);
```

> Why do we need to set the port in line 3? `app.set('port', port);`

You do not need that - it is not necessary for Express to run or function.  That is presumably just there so that if other code wants to somehow know what the port is, it can ask the `app` object what the port is.

> Where is this setting used? (Is it in the server object? If so, how does it know to use this setting?)

I'm not aware of anywhere that it is used.  If you leave out the `app.set('port', port)` line, Express will still work just fine.